# Show a loader during timeout? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I  have this code

```
return function (dispatch) {
    console.log("\t dispatch");
    var timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
        // rest of code here
        console.log("setTimeout 5 secondi");
    }, 3000);
}
```

I wanted to ask,is it possible to add logic while timeout?
For example ,show a loader while doing timeout?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean showing the loader before calling `setTimeout()` and hiding it in the callback of `setTimeout()`?

```
return function (dispatch) {
    console.log("\t dispatch");
    showLoader(); // here you can display some graphic
    var timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
        // rest of code here
        console.log("setTimeout 5 secondi");
        hideLoader(); // hide the loader graphic after 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
}
```